# OnItemCommand function not working with asp Linkbutton in Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, asplinkbutton

I´m having some wierd issus with my asp:Linkbutton functionality in my asp:ListView.
Here is my code:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvData" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lvData_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="lvData_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>... </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    ...
    <td>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="ItemLink" runat="server" CommandName="View" Text='<%# Eval("NameOfBatch")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
    ...
```

my code-behind is like this:

```
    protected void lvData_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{    
    string smu = "";
}
```

if I put a breakpoint on string smu it never goes there. 
The only thing that happens is that my table dissapears and nothing else.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Do you rebind the data in each postback?

Comment: That was the reason. I had to run a function to bind the data after postback. THX !

Answer (score 0):

Set the CausesValidation property to false on the controls if you have validation on the form and  don't want them to trigger the validation.

Comment: For more help visit the link with same type of question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022734/listview-fields-not-getting-posted